# Ajax to notify about variable change on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm using Django and JQuery. I basically want to refresh team's page when the game starts (a game is started manually so the exact time is uknown). So I send an ajax request to the server asking whether the game started, but I have to do it continiously, so I'm not sure what's better:
1. Have a javascript while loop that keeps sending a request
2. Have a while loop on the server side that waits to respond until the game starts.

Or maybe there is some other better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You're receiving a number of close votes because of the way you've worded this question. I know you've already got an answer, but I think you could avoid having this close if you reword it to ask more about the benefits and problems of each solution you propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 which you specify is called **polling** and which will generate multiple calls to server so it is not recommended.

Approach 2 is not feasible since you will have time out.

Right way(efficiently) to do this type of thing is via **WebSockets** or some kind of **Push Notification** from server. few libraries are 
http://socket.io/
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

If this had helped you don't forgot to mark it as answer :)

Comment: thanks! any performance limitations that polling brings? i'll have 10-20 teams at once at most, so shouldn't be a problem on server side, but the team's internet connection may be pretty bad.

Comment: @AndreiIvanov,if you think that your team's connection may be pretty bad then polling too frequently might not be the best way to do it,in that case webscokets are best way to achieve it, but if you need some quick solution then you can customize your polling mechanism , may by by sending back when it should next poll.

Answer (score 0):

Polling is simplest option since it will work with plain Django system.

There exists several other techniques to keep connection open and send messages to client (browser), like websockets or server sent events (sse), but those require additional components in infrastructure than just Django.

And you can't keep server waiting, browsers and frontend webservers usually do have time limits to detect dead connections so your connection would be terminated before game starts.

Answer (score 0):

Your server knows when the game will start, like 5pm?  Tell the browser's JavaScript to start polling at 4:59:40